# Is there a PdfSmartCopy Equivalent in iText7

Tags: itext7

Is there an equivalent to iText 5's PdfSmartCopy class in iText 7? If not, how do I achieve the same functionality in iText 7?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the `SmartMode` property of a `PdfWriter` to `true`:

```
/**
 * Sets the smart mode.
 * <p/>
 * In smart mode when resources (such as fonts, images,...) are
 * encountered, a reference to these resources is saved
 * in a cache, so that they can be reused.
 * This requires more memory, but reduces the file size
 * of the resulting PDF document.
 */
public PdfWriter setSmartMode(boolean smartMode)
```

Using such a `PdfWriter` to copy pages to is the equivalent of using a `PdfSmartCopy`.